Are binary R packages compatible across different versions of R on Linux?
For a compiled R package on Linux, should the compiled package install and work fine on versions of R later than the version used to compile it?
The context is that I’m making a (private) repository of compiled packages, and wondering if there should be separation by R version. (Will also have separation by major version of distribution, in this case Debian)

AFAIK, yes, if only the minor version of R differs. No, otherwise.

@Roland Ah thanks! To confirm, minor is the Y in version X.Y.Z? So packages compiled with R 4.0.0 would be compatible with R 4.1.0? And... why do you think this? (I guess I'm looking for some sort of rough guarantee)

From my experience: if they are using system libraries which were updated in meantime, they will throw errors. And change from 4.0.x to 4.1.x required recompilation of the packages. You might have to check rig (https://github.com/r-lib/rig) to see how two versions will behave.

@MichalCharemza No, I mean the Z.

https://rstats.wtf/maintaining-r.html#how-to-transfer-your-library-when-updating-r

You do not to transfer a library if you install into a directory without an R version in the first place.  On Windows, you could use something like C:/R/library/ and re-use this by setting R_LIBS_USER or R_LIBS_SITE in either the system or user-specific Renviron.  Ditto on Linux or macOS if you place your library below /opt or /usr/local/ and keep it.

@Roland Thanks! https://rstats.wtf/maintaining-r.html#how-to-transfer-your-library-when-updating-r is exactly what I was looking for (feel free to make an answer)

Yes, it generally does as the 'ABI' (application binary interface) tends to be stable across R releases.
But if it changes, and recompilation is required / imposed this is clearly signalled.  For example on my machine I have a (leaving it unnamed for now, local) package built ages ago. Loading it yields
> library(abcDEF)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘abcDEF’:
 package ‘abcDEF’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
> 

On the other hand, I just loaded another package that was compiled / installed locally in 2020 without a problem. Its DESCRIPTION file of the installed package says
Built: R 4.0.0; x86_64-pc-linux-gnu; 2020-04-26 22:49:08.53212 UTC; unix

and I am now running R 4.4.1.
PS: Calling installed.packages() tells you in column 'Built' which R version was used to install it.  In a Docker container I see
> IP <- installed.packages()
> table(IP[,"Built"])

4.2.0 4.3.0 4.3.2 4.4.0 4.4.1 
    4     8     1     6    14 
> 

further demonstrating that while can force yourself to reinstall on major.minor changes it really is not required (outside the aforementioned, and rare, documented ABI breaks).
